# error on mapping entities : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I having an error :

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical
>   on the datacontext Initialisation.

My database contains several tables, the AttachedMeter table has as Primary key composed of

- a foreign key to the table Meter (MeterId)
- an Id, who linkd to the table Gateway (GatewayId)
- a timestamp

The entity :

```
public class AttachedMeter : IEquatable<AttachedMeter>
{
    public int GatewayId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public virtual Configuration Configuration { get; set; }

    public int MeterId { get; set; }
    public virtual Meter Meter { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        this.ConfigurationElements = new HashSet<ConfigurationElement>();
        this.AttachedMeters = new HashSet<AttachedMeter>();
    }

    public int GatewayId { get; set; }
    public virtual Gateway Gateway { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public int? RefId { get; set; }

    public int ConfigurationStatus { get; set; }

    public int? ProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ConfigurationElement> ConfigurationElements { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AttachedMeter> AttachedMeters { get; set; }
}

public class Gateway : IEquatable<Gateway>
{
    public Gateway()
    {
        this.Scans = new HashSet<Scan>();
        this.Configurations = new HashSet<Configuration>();
        this.MonitoringDatas = new HashSet<MonitoringData>();
        this.AdditionalInformations = new HashSet<AdditionalInformation>();
        // to Delete for the UHF version 3.0
      /*  this.AttachedMeters = new HashSet<AttachedMeter>();*/
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public Guid? TreeNodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual TreeNode TreeNode { get; set; }

    public int? ProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Scan> Scans { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MonitoringData> MonitoringDatas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AdditionalInformation> AdditionalInformations { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping :

```
public class AttachedMeterMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AttachedMeter>
{
    public AttachedMeterMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(am => new { am.GatewayId, am.Timestamp, am.MeterId});

        this.HasRequired(am => am.Configuration)
            .WithMany(c => c.AttachedMeters)
            .HasForeignKey(am => new {am.GatewayId, am.Timestamp});

        this.HasRequired(am => am.Meter)
            .WithMany(m => m.AttachedMeters)
            .HasForeignKey(am => am.MeterId);
    }
}

    public ConfigurationMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(c => new { c.GatewayId, c.Timestamp });

        this.Property(c => c.Timestamp).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.ConfigurationStatus).IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired(c => c.Gateway)
            .WithMany(g => g.Configurations)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.GatewayId);

        this.HasOptional(c => c.Profile)
            .WithMany(p => p.Configurations)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProfileId);

        this.Property(c => c.RefId);

        this.HasMany(c => c.AttachedMeters);
    }
}

    public GatewayMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(g => g.Id);
        this.Property(g => g.Identifier).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);

        this.HasOptional(g => g.TreeNode)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(g => g.TreeNodeId);

        this.HasOptional(g => g.Profile)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(g => g.ProfileId);

        this.HasMany(g => g.Scans);
        this.HasMany(g => g.Configurations);
        this.HasMany(g => g.MonitoringDatas);
}
```

At the initialization of databaseContext, the program throws an error like this:
"The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical"

Surely, it's the relationship between these object, but I don't know how... 
Where is my error?